# $E$-field between dielectric and plate in parallel plate capacitor and Feynman's claim

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge, capacitance, dielectric

Feynman says about $E_{0}$ below
[image]

> Note that the field $E_{0}$ between the metal plate and the surface of the dielectric is higher than the field $E$; it corresponds to $\sigma _{free}$ alone.

$\sigma _{pol}$ is the surface charge density induced by polarizing the dielectric. Why does $E_{0}$ correspond to $\sigma _{free}$ *alone*? It strikingly makes no sense from the schematic. If we apply Gauss's law, we can clearly see that **both** $\sigma_{free}$ **and** $\sigma _{pol}$ contribute to $E_{0}$, not just $\sigma_{free}$.

Answer (score 0):

To see Feynmann's point, draw a different Gaussian surface that encloses half the plate, but none of the dielectric. This shows that the electric field $E_0$ is entirely determined by the plate’s charge density $\sigma_{free}$ *alone*.

How about that Gaussian surface in the figure?  Doesn't it show that $\sigma_{pol}$ contributes to $E_0$?  There are three answers to this:

1) Note that the lines of field start at $\sigma_{free}$ charges in the plate, and either terminate in the $\sigma_{pol}$ charges on the surface of the dielectric or continue on through the dielectric:  Those lines come entirely from the plate's $\sigma_{free}$, and all $\sigma_{pol}$ does is terminate them before they reach the field within the dielectric.

2) More mathematically, since both the field within the dielectric and the charge on the surface of the dielectric $\sigma_{pol}$ are included in the calculation of the Gaussian surface in the figure, all that figure shows is that $\sigma_{free} - \sigma_{pol}$ determines the field in the dielectric:  It's silent on $E_0$.

3) Finally, linguistic:  Feynmann says "corresponds to $\sigma_{free}$ alone", which means is caused by $\sigma_{free}$ and can be calculated starting with $\sigma_{free}$.  $\sigma_{free}$ and $E_0$ *also* cause $\sigma_{pol}$, but that doesn't change the correctness of Feynmann's statement.

Comment: There is no reason to chose the Gaussian surface that excludes $\sigma _{pol}$ over the one that includes it. And we can clearly see from the schematic that $\sigma_{pol}$ contributes to $E_{0}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I've added a bit to try to clarify.